# boldface (and other things) fail when xelatex used with pslatex package

Tags: xetex, fontspec

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
  
\usepackage{pslatex}
%\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\bfseries Hello World!
\end{document}
```

With `pdflatex`, the PDF comes out as expected. But with `xelatex`, the "Hello World!" is not in bold. However I can uncomment the `fontspec` line and then with `xelatex` it is back to having bold.

Is this all expected behavior? And if so, can someone explain what's going on?

In my application, there are `.tex` files that (presently) always use `pslatex`. Sometimes they are processed with `pdflatex` and other times with `xelatex`. I noticed the latter had an absence of bold (as well as small caps) and investigated. And came to this point.

Comment: pslatex made a bit of sense with latex209nfss for which I wrote it in 1991 or so, it's not very useful with latexe2e pdflatex, and not useful at all with xelatex or lualatex, what is the aim here? there must be an alternative

Comment: `pslatex` is a legacy font package. With XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX it even does not use times, reported by the font warning: ``Font shape `TU/ptm/m/n' undefined using `TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 457``. For XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX you should use `fontspec` and `\setmainfont`, `\setsansfont` etc. to setup a times like text font, a helvetica like text font etc. and `unicode-math` to setup a suitable math font. But if you really want to try the legacy fonts with XeLaTeX, you may try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. But don't expect correct output for all unicode chars (e.g. `ß` would be incorrect).

Comment: Thank you @DavidCarlisle. The application has a good deal of legacy code and I suspect (now more than ever with your comment) that `pslatex` is no longer serving a purpose and should be removed. FWIW, it's WeBWorK generating PDF homework sets for students.

Comment: @cabohah Thanks. I think we are content with the default font here, and it sounds like I should examine simply removing `pslatex`.

Comment: @alex.jordan The `pslatex` package *is* serving a purpose, namely to allow running LaTeX over older documents that use it. Loading it in newer document isn't recommended (to use understatement). Where “newer” means “after 2000” or so.

Comment: @egreg I did not mean it is not serving a purpose in general. I meant it is no longer serving a purpose in my application where it is still being loaded 20+ years later.

Comment: @alex.jordan Some applications tend to lag behind the developments…